# How to enable the textbox content after enteringthe password for the textbox?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fire the event GotFocus() on the text box `Txttravel` which is disabled. I want that in case we want to edit this textbox- we have to enter the password and then the textbox is enabled and we can edit it. Help to achieve it. I tried below code. But it is not trigerring when the textbox is in disabled state.

```
Private Sub Txttravel_GotFocus()

Dim Password As String

Password = InputBox("Enter password to edit this field:", "Password")
    If Password = "Cloudbu@hcl" Then
    Txttravel.Enabled = True

   Me.Range("A1").Select

   End If
   Txttravel.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Disabled controls cannot get focus. You could lock the control instead of disabling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a control can **get the focus** only if it's **visible and enabled** as said by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211410(v=office.11).aspx).

---

### Alternative 1 : Selecting another control

As an alternative I recommend you just select another control in your form if the password is wrong and not disabling your textbox.

Try changing your code to this

```
Private Sub Txttravel_Enter()
    Dim Password As String

    Password = InputBox("Enter password to edit this field:", "Password")

    If Password = "Cloudbu@hcl" Then
        Txttravel.SetFocus
    Else
        'Select another control in your form here
        TextBox2.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### Alternative 2 proposed by @KostasK : Use of the Locked property

As proposed by KostasK in the comments, you can lock the textbox.

```
Private Sub Txttravel_Enter()
    Dim Password As String

    Password = InputBox("Enter password to edit this field:", "Password")

    If Password = "Cloudbu@hcl" Then
        Txttravel.Locked = False
    Else
        Txttravel.Locked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** Make sure to place this code in your form with: Right clic on your form > View Code

Comment: You cannot enter a control if it's disabled - the event will never fire.

Comment: @KostasK.Yeah I just realized that after checking on Internet, thank you. I provided another solution that works.

Comment: I think the previous approach was better once you change the `Enabled` property to `Locked`.

Comment: @KostasK. Both ways work, I added you alternative in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this!!